# Unable to iterate over files using ZSH alias

Tags: linux, zsh, alias

I have simple command to iterate JPG files

```
for f in *.JPG;do echo "Processing $f";done
```

The terminal output is as follows:

```
Processing IMG_0316.JPG
Processing IMG_0317.JPG
Processing IMG_0318.JPG
Processing IMG_0319.JPG
```

However when I put this exact command as an alias

```
alias listjpgonly="for f in *.JPG;do echo 'Processing $f';done"
```

I only get one file and can only process that one file

```
Processing IMG_0327.JPG
Processing IMG_0327.JPG
Processing IMG_0327.JPG
Processing IMG_0327.JPG
```

I noticed it only echo the last JPG file.

Any help on this be great - Thanks

Comment: Because the RHS of the alias is enclosed in double quotes, `$f` gets expanded to whatever value it has at the time of definition